# how to pass ahref from codebehind and need to open that new window

Tags: webforms, href, code-behind

I need to pass some URL from code behind and when user clicks on that link it has to be opened in new window.

Ex: `string link="<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>Microsoft</a>";`

once above link is displayed on UI if user clicks on Microsoft it has to be open in new window instead of same window..

I tried in above format but when I click on that Microsoft it is opening in same page.

I searched for the solution but couldn't find appropriate one. How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, I think you need to add `target="_blank"` within the `<a>` HTML tag.